# Putting getdate()'s data into a string

Tags: sql-server-2005

In sqlserver 2005,  I am using this query:

`select getdate()` or `print getdate()`

I want to use this returned date as a string to get access to:

1. the month
2. The year(last two digits)
3. date (eg: 01)
4. time (eg: 5:12)

I want to concatenate all the data. All that should be in string format.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: **ALL formatting should be done on the client.**
Now that we got that out of the way look into [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) functions.
CONVERT offers lots of styles you can use, while DATEPART returns part of the date as integer which you can convert to varchar.

Just note that there are a lot of functions like these on the web already so searching for some wouldn't be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have all the pieces as strings you can concatenate them and use CONVERT()

```
declare @my_year varchar(4)
declare @my_month varchar(4)
declare @my_day varchar(4)
declare @my_hour varchar(4)
declare @my_minute varchar(4)
declare @my_second varchar(4)

set @my_year = '1900'
set @my_month = '05'
set @my_day = '13'
set @my_hour = '05'
set @my_minute = '12'
set @my_second = '00'

select CONVERT(datetime,@my_year + 
                    @my_month + 
                    @my_day + 
                    ' ' + 
                    @my_hour + ':' + 
                    @my_minute + ':' + 
                    @my_second)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120)
```

to get:

```
2011-05-11 15:02:36
```

and manipulate that?